# don't have related_posts.rb or one of its dependencies installed

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am trying to implement **related_posts-jekyll_plugin** plugin to show the related post based on post tag on jekyll blog. When running jekyll server I got following error, how can I solve it?

`$ jekyll serve`

[image: don't have related_posts.rb or one of its dependencies installed error]

```
Configuration file: D:/git/blog/_config.yml
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have D:/git/blog/_plugins/related_posts.rb or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll/post' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!
jekyll 3.6.0 | Error:  D:/git/blog/_plugins/related_posts.rb
```

My _config.yml file contains following content.

```
title: Kiran's blog | Kiran Shahi is a .NET developer from Nepal
email: mail@example.com
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  Welcome to kiran's blog. Kiran Shahi is a .NET guy. He is passionate about technology.
baseurl: "/blog" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
twitter_username: itskirans
github_username:  kiranshahi
future: true

paginate: 5


# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
gems:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-paginate
exclude:
  - Gemfile
- Gemfile.lock
```

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. We can’t run your screenshot as code.

Comment: @tadman I have mention errors as text as well as image.

Comment: The text in that screenshot may as well be invisible, it's super tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Although we can't see your config file, It Looks like you have related_posts.rb in your gem list in your config file. As this plugin is not a gem but just a plugin file you do not need to list it there. Just remove it from that section.

Comment: Since I cannot post all the code in _config.yml file. I have mentioned it in question.

Comment: Ok, I took a look at that plugin and it seems to be very old, and doesn't work with newer versions of jekyll. Is this the plugin you're using? https://github.com/lawrencewoodman/related_posts-jekyll_plugin? If so, This fork seems to be more up to date - https://github.com/SimonBackx/related_posts-jekyll_plugin

Comment: Yes I am using this plugin.

Comment: Perfect. Then try moving to that new version of the plugin that was created by SimonBackx, and it might work with the newest version of Jekyll